# gRPC and WSO2 Api Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Does `WSO2 Api Manager` support services using `gRPC`?

It would be great to have the possibility to publish into the `WSO2-AM` and not just services using `OpenAPI`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIM doesn't support gRPC and seems it is not in roadmap for synapse gateway. But the next ballerina based gateway support gRPC. But still APIM(2.5.0 next release), doesn't support gRPC as a transport.